# How to mark the selected item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I'm building a page with html, css and javascript... using backend java, jsp.

I have a header that fits all pages... I "include" it.

How do I mark the item referring to the page that opens differently("activity")?

My javascript knowledge is almost nil... I tried like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("li a[href='" + location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, 255) + "']").addClass("itemActive");
});
```

CSS:

```
.itemActive {
    color: red;
}
```

The home page is not marked as active... after clicks on other pages the code works... when I click on the home again does not work.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="home.do">Painel</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="gerencardapio.do">Cardapio</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="integracao.do">Integração</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery as a library in your page? The code snippet you provided is using jQuery (a JavaScript library) instead of JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think so. Do I include or use a javascript code?

Comment: My first thought is that I need to see some html!  But possibly the "home.do" link is actually a routed shortcut, like /~ or just /, or is a url re-write or similar...  Either of these would explain why the Painel text is not being highlighted in red as the URL would not match the `a [href]` value.

Comment: @ne1410 Updated, and now?

Comment: Hmm ok, well that seems to match the URL bar, and presumably the location.href... I wonder if you put a line like this `console.log(location.href);` inside your `document.ready` method, as the first line - what kind of entries you see (pressing F12 in your browser > Console - to view the console).

Comment: Ideally it should be your backend that marks a link as "current" (by giving it an extra class), not frontend code.

Comment: @YellowAfterlife I can't imagine, can you show me an example?

Comment: When you form the page response on the backend, you would check that the URL of the `nav-item`, and give it an extra class, suppose `<li class="nav-item current">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `active` class for your first `<li>` i.e. Painel and give the desired CSS to it. This will solve your problem.